# Remove all substrings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have 'defs' table(def as TEXT, ref as INT), where `def` is a word's definition, and `ref` is a reference to a word.

**Goal:**

I need for every definition(def) to delete all repeating definitions (that's will be contained in a longest one)

**Initial conditions:**

1. Count of raws is 300 000
2. Length of defination can be 5 000 symbols.

**Example:**

**defs:**

- Animal with big ears - 1
- Animal with big ears and big nose - 1
- Big animal with tail - 1
- Small furry mammal - 2
- Small furry mammal with gray tail - 2

**Output:**

- Animal with bit ears and big nose - 1
- Small furry mammal with gray tail - 2

I **have** idea with hashcodes, but I can't finish my idea :(

Any idea how to get it done?

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?, please don't use `text` for your data, it's deprecated and only exists for backwards compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you?

```
declare @table table(def text, ref int);

insert into @table
values
('Animal with bit ears', 1),
('Animal with bit ears and big nose', 1),
('Big animal with tail', 1),
('Small furry mammal', 2),
('Small furry mammal with gray tail', 2)
;

delete defs
from (
    select row_number() over (
            partition by ref order by DATALENGTH(def) desc
            ) rank_
    from @table
    ) defs
where defs.rank_ > 1;

select * from @table;
```

Comment: Something to note, if two rows have 'def' equal datalengths then one will arbitrarily be chosen. If this is not desired you could use 'rank' instead of 'row_number'.

Comment: If its the correct answer you could consider marking it as the correct answer.